# Why is it common to plot $xG(x,Q^2)$ and not simply $G(x,Q^2)$?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, visualization

I'm trying to understand the modern description of high-energy scattering processes involving hadrons in the initial states. The phenomenological parton distributions functions play a central role, and as I understand it at the moment, if we are e.g. talking about gluons, the function $G(x, Q^2)$ is the probability of finding a gluon with momentum fraction $x$ inside the hadron if the transmitted four-momentum is $Q^2$.

When these functions are plotted, I often encounter plots showing $x G(x, Q^2)$ instead of simply $G(x, Q^2)$. Why is this so? Is this just because the plots look a lot nicer if plotted this way? Or is there some deeper reason behind this that I haven't figured out yet?

As an example, take a look at the plot used [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parton_%28particle_physics%29#Parton_distribution_functions).
[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CTEQ6_parton_distribution_functions.png]

(Picture from: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CTEQ6_parton_distribution_functions.png)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CTEQ6_parton_distribution_functions.png)

Comment: Honestly I really don't know, but just a guess: to make it better visible how fast $G\to\infty$ for $x\to0$? Though an ordinary logarithmic scale would probably do that job better.

Comment: $G$ cannot approach infinity... it is a probability density function.

Comment: @Adam: there's no reason it can't approach infinity as $x\to 0$, as at least the gluon PDF seems to do, as long as the proper normalization conditions on the function as a whole are satisfied.

Comment: @David:  Ahhh... right.  I had trouble imagining this, but thinking about the Dirac delta function it makes sense.  Sorry, I haven't been in school for a year and I'm a bit rusty. :)

Comment: Fair enough, I forget little things like that all the time :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you say, "$G(x,Q^2)$ is the probability of finding a gluon with momentum fraction $x$ inside the hadron if the transmitted four-momentum is $Q^2$."  In other words, $G(x,Q^2)$ is a [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Further_details).  As you can see from the article, in this case the [expectation value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value) of the variable is

$E[X] = \int_{0} ^{1} x\cdot G(x,Q^2) dx$

The plot of $x\cdot G(x,Q^2)$ then gives an intuitive sense of the "contribution" to the expectation value of the probability density function.

Comment: the integral should be from 0 to 1. An additional interpretation is that the area under the curve is the total momentum fraction of this parton type.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the integral.  I'm not actually an HEP guy, I just recognized the statistics of the situation.